# Inconsistent number of items for each row in grid

Tags: html, css, gridview

I'm using css grid to construct my image layout. I'm looking at the guideliness about css grid, most of them each row has the same number of items, or merge with some columns to form the desired result. In my case, I have an odd number of items for each row. How can I achieve in the photo below?

**HTML**

```
<div class="thumbnails>
  <div class="image1"></div>
  <div class="image2"></div>
  <div class="image3"></div>
  <div class="image4"></div>
  <div class="image5"></div>
  <div class="image6"></div>
  ...
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.thumbnails{
   display:grid;
   grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
   grid-template-areas: ""
                        "" 
                        "" 
                        "";
}
```

**Photo**

[image]